# React with .NET Web API Hosting on IIS

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, iis, deployment

I am trying to host a React app inside a .NET API to host on IIS.

It works fine while trying to run on locahost. However, when I try to access the website through the corresponding public URL it gives me ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

I have checked SSL settings and main site configuration but that did not work. Also, I have tried to host a static website on that URL and it worked so no problem in the DNS record.

I have added the following URL Rewrite rules:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <!-- Redirect HTTP to HTTPS -->
    <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <!-- Handle React Router client-side routing -->
    <rule name="React Router Routes" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

This is the configuration in `Program.cs`:

```
// Enable CORS
builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("corspolicy", build =>
{
    build.WithOrigins("*").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
}));

// Register React app
builder.Services.AddSpaStaticFiles(options =>
{
    options.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
});

app.UseCors("corspolicy");

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
    //if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    //{
    //    spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
    //}
});
```

Please note that the app is working fine on localhost with api Integration.

After checking IIS logs, a 500 response was there from my device IP to the hostname still don't know why on public DNS it gives 500 while not on locahost.

I enabled Failed Request Tracing and got a very long file but this is a sample:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>1</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-08-08T11:10:59.811Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000447-0005-FD00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="23840" ThreadID="15608"/>
  <Computer>NHIC-WEB-01</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000447-0005-FD00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">RewriteModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">1</Data>
  <Data Name="fIsPostNotification">false</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>NOTIFY_MODULE_START</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">BEGIN_REQUEST</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>

<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>1</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-08-08T11:10:59.811Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000447-0005-FD00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="23840" ThreadID="15608"/>
  <Computer>NHIC-WEB-01</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000447-0005-FD00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">ConfigurationValidationModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">1</Data>
  <Data Name="fIsPostNotification">false</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>NOTIFY_MODULE_START</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">BEGIN_REQUEST</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
```

This is my first time deploying a react app with .net to IIS so I am struggling to come up with a blueprint for upcoming apps.

Trying to publish the React as a main website on IIS and adding the .NET API as a child app. It work fine on localhost but when accessing the website on the public hostname I receive too many redirects for the api requests only. So, pages are loaded fine but all API calls returns too many redirects

Comment: Use Visual Studio or `dotnet new` to create an ASP.NET Core with React SPA project and study how it works. Then you know how to modify your current project.

Comment: Noting specific. My point is that it works on IIS localhost fine

Comment: You can use failed request tracking to view detailed error information.

Comment: I have tried to do so but it wasn't logged I don't know why.  Shouldn't it be just a specific configuration for React and .NE ?

Comment: Refer to this link: [Using Failed Request Tracing to Trace Rewrite Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) and make sure you have enabled failed request tracking.

Comment: @LexLi nothing useful there since they are using outdated React

Comment: The SPA middleware approach applies to newer React versions, if you carefully learn it through, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/intro?view=aspnetcore-7.0#architecture-of-single-page-application-templates. That frees you up from learning URL rewriting.

Comment: @LexLi My approach is working fine on IIS localhost while not on public hostname that is my main issue. I am aware of the middleware but several approaches also advises to use something similar to the code above.

Comment: Then I wonder how much of "My approach is working fine on IIS localhost" is true: 1) your rewrite rules have no exception for REST API calls, so your complete IIS settings for the React web app and the backend API might be messy (but you didn't reveal them and only claimed it works). 2) What are the "several approaches"? Unreliable or partial posts are overall harmful.

Comment: That's why I posted my questions to get an answer. Forget about the approach that I followed, lets say I follow a better approach by hosting each one as a separate application on IIS and the client will be sending the request to the API. My client will be on the public hostname binding but what about the server ? I don't think that it will be on the server localhost.

Answer (score 0):

So after several tries and referring to different resources. The approach that worked for me is to host the client app on IIS, and host the API as a child application under the client app with the suitable alias.

So whenever the client sends a request to the backend it will start with /{alias} then the request route.

Also following this approach, no need to use any specific SPA middlewares:

```
app.UseCors("corspolicy");
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
```